# How to config in step 4 in a Distributed API-M Deployment with Traffic Manager Separation

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have deployed tm , cp , gw at 3 vms for wso2 apimanager, but how to config deployment.toml in a distribution deployment with tm separation? I don't know what should i do in step4 from [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/deploying-wso2-api-m-in-a-distributed-setup/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the same steps with the traffic-manager separation as well. There's a separate doc for traffic-manager separated pattern[1]. You can refer that during the setup.

[1]- https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/deploying-wso2-api-m-in-a-distributed-setup-with-tm-separated/

Comment: Yes, I follow it to deploy with tm separation , but i I don't know what should i do in step4 , it's not clear to me in step4.

Comment: If you have different host names, you can create certificates for those and them to the key store and trust store. The default `wso2carbon` entry is corresponding to localhost only.

Comment: how to import my certificates to key store and trust store

Comment: You can use keytool for this. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/security/configuring-keystores/keystore-basics/creating-new-keystores/#step-2-importing-certificates-to-the-keystore